# Import .pbix (power BI) file into the workspace using php (multipart form-data post)

Tags: azure, multipartform-data, powerbi, php-curl, powerbi-embedded

I want to import local pbix fle to created workspace in azure power bi account. I already created workspaceId using REST API. However when i try to import pbix file that gives 200 ok status instead of 202 accepted response with Id.

Here is the reference code i followed [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-iframe#import-pbix-file-into-the-workspace)

> POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/mypbiapp/workspaces/32960a09-6366-4208-a8bb-9e0678cdbb9d/imports?datasetDisplayName=mydataset01
> Authorization: AppKey MpaUgrTv5e... Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
> boundary="A300testx"
>
> --A300testx Content-Disposition: form-data
>
> {the content (binary) of .pbix file}
> --A300testx--

I used php curl request to called Rest API and below shows the code which i tried,

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/XXXXXX/workspaces/XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXX/imports?datasetDisplayName=mydataset01');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$postData = array(
        'datafile' => '@C:\Users\Desktop\report1.pbix',
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
        "Authorization: AppKey R97v4Fe5=="
) );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
echo $response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ( $ch );
```

As a response I'm getting status code as 200 ok with json

> {"id":"0331a80d-6f23-4626-9624-1f6b98ce373a"}

However this new dataset was not created in workspaceID. Please help me to find the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for multipart form-data post with php curl, This code works for me

```
$name = 'report1';
$file = 'report1.pbix';
$boundary = "----------BOUNDARY";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/XXXXXX/workspaces/XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXX/imports?datasetDisplayName=mydataset01');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$postdata .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$postdata .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" . $name . "\"; filename=\"" . $file . "\"\r\n";
$postdata .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
$postdata .= file_get_contents($file);
$postdata .= "\r\n";
$postdata .= "--" . $boundary . "--\r\n";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $$postdata);
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
        "Authorization: AppKey R97v4Fe5==",
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postdata)
) );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
echo $response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ( $ch );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ready to use version of the given solution

```
public function import($access_key, $workspace_collection_name, $workspace_id, $file_path, $file_name, $display_name, $nameConflict = 'Overwrite')
{

    $boundary = "----------BOUNDARY";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/$workspace_collection_name/workspaces/$workspace_id/imports?datasetDisplayName=$display_name&nameConflict=$nameConflict");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $postdata = '';
    $postdata .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $postdata .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"; filename=\"" . $file_path . "\"\r\n";
    $postdata .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    $postdata .= file_get_contents($file_path);
    $postdata .= "\r\n";
    $postdata .= "--" . $boundary . "--\r\n";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Authorization: AppKey " . $access_key,
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postdata)
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        return 'curl error';
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;

}
```